# Share Java classes between war files in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, war, ear

I am using Tomcat 7 as a servlet container and I have two war files (two projects in Eclipse). The problem is, that I want to share classes between both deployed war files.
But this is not possible with Tomcat / Servlet specifications as far as I know. Both deployed web applications seems to be are isolated from each other.

So I read, I am a newbie, from JBoss as an application server in which I can deploy ear files (so I can put multiple war files into it) and then I can share classes between them?

So my question: Do you agree with my statement, is it possible to do this with JBoss? And do I have to make changes or can I put easily both in an ear file and deploy it with JBoss and it will work?

Best Regards, Tim.

Comment: I am newbie with JBoss application server. So dont know whether it is possible with JBoss. But, you can have shared jar in tomcat. You need to configure catalina.properties "shared.loader" property. But yes, you can't share classes from two different war in tomcat.

Comment: But in JBoss I can share classes from two different wars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 easy options. Both require you to define the shared classes in a separate project (JAR), let's call it *SHARED*. Now, when it comes to deployment you have 2 options:

1. copy *SHARED.jar* to Tomcat's lib folder and you're done.
2. reference *SHARED.jar* in your WebApp, when exporting your WAR from eclipse the tooling will create a JAR, place it in WebApp's WEB-INF/lib folder, and create the WAR (see screenshot).

If you go with option #1 it is important to understand that the same classes are shared between the WebApp classloaders (Tomcat system classloader), so you'd go with this option only if you want to share state between different WebApps (e.g. Singletons).

BTW: The screenshot is made using Eclipse 3.6 + WTP...

[image]

Comment: Hm, not sure... you need a solution for Tomcat, not for JBoss, right?

Comment: If it is possible with Tomcat, this would be fine. But if I have two wars, then I have to use JBoss and it will work? Then I do not know the difference between a full application server like JBoss and a servlet container like Tomcat in combination with this problem war <-> ear. I thought in an ear file I can put several jars and wars and they will run in JBoss as one big application and in Tomcat I can not do this.

Comment: Exactly, in Tomcat you have to deploy several WARs. Which is fully supported, so you could have 10 WARs running in one Tomcat instance (JVM).

Comment: Okay, and with JBoss I can deploy all in one ear and I can share classes between wars in JBoss. In Tomcat I have to do your way with a jar file, otherwise I can not share classes in Tomcat, right?