# how to get WebApplicationContext outside current servlet context?

Tags: java, spring, servlets

There are two WARs deployed in Tomcat (or other server), foo1.war and foo2.war.
All spring beans are defined in foo1.war, but is it possible to get these spring beans in the servlet that deployed in foo2.war?
I cannot just use `WebApplicationContextUtils` to get the `WebApplicationContext`, right? They are different WAR.

thanks

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807818/share-java-classes-between-war-files-in-tomcat can help you.

Comment: @Tichodroma: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807818/share-java-classes-between-war-files-in-tomcat is about sharing classes and instances, but not Spring contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you *can* get the `WebApplicationContext` of the other app, if you expose the servlet context and call `servletContext.getContext("/otherapp").getAttribute(..)`, but that's ugly.

You can have instances of the same bean definitions if you simply move the common definitions to a `common.xml` and include it in both projects.

If you need to communicate some data betweent the two apps, use another mechanism: web services (soap, rest), messaging (jmx).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Bozho answer: you can also share instance data (e.g. singletons), when the two WARs are deployed in a single EAR. You should be able to expose the appContexts as statically visible fields in a class provided by EAR and thus visible to both WARs.